# Track website click on custom variable and get value of variable

Tags: php, wordpress, google-tag-manager

Very new to GTM. Looks like it might be able to achieve this? But need some assistance.

I am sending out emails with a custom variable of "r" and attaching the "user email-address" to that variable.

So in the email I have links that I want to track like this:

```
https://www.mywebsite.com/services/?r=user12@gmail.com
```

So, in theory - I want to ONLY track when the variable exists and capturing a few things ( only if variable "r" exists ):

1. Timestamp of when they visited
2. Page Title of where they landed
3. Value of "r"

Thinking this could be pretty easy with Google Tag Manager, but wanted some expert advice before heading down that rabbit hole.

Thanks.

Comment: in the past we use a lot the referer tag. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer it was commonly use to know how people get to your site.  btw just a comment.

Comment: While you seem to get many great responses about technical feasibility, mostly referring to Google Analytics, please note, that you are not allowed to send personally identifiable information (PII) into Google Analytics. Email is one of the named examples of this. For further details on this you might want to check this: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6366371?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Google Tag Manager is not a tracking tool, so GTM alone will not help you.

Google Tag Manager can easily extract the "r" parameter from the destination url if you create via "Variables/New" in the interface a url type variable and set it to "query":

[image: GTM url type variable UI]

You can also get the page title by extracting the value of the global document.title variable in a Javascript variable:

[image: GTM javascript type variable UI]

You could use a Custom Javascript (not the same as a mere Javascript variable) to compute a timestamp, but most tracking solutions record a timestamp by themselves.

What GTM will not do, however, is to store the data anywhere. GTM is a tool to deploy tracking solutions, it is not a tracking solution itself (you could e.g. use Google Analytics, or write a simple tracking script yourself).

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. Very good. So, GTM will not store the results anywhere ? Strange - I guess you hook it to GA, right ? A simple tracking script,.. where to start..

Comment: You start by figuring out how much traffic (especially how much concurrent traffic) you expect - the solution will look much different depending on if you need to track one, or a hundred, or hundreds if thousands of users.

Answer (score 1):

You also could use Google Analytics for this.

When you go to Analytics go to the main menu of your website and choose: Behavior > Site content > All Pages and in the search box on the right side, just type in the ?r to get an overview of all url's that analytics recorded that has an ?r in it.

Hope this helps.